# Div contenedor solo se quede con el ultimo div y no acumule

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

El `JS` que utilizo llena el `div  class .ajax-file-upload-container`

se llena con otro div

```
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="display: none; width: 420px;">
```

y mientras siga seleccionado con el elemento file seguirá acumulando así

```
<div class="ajax-file-upload-container">
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="display: none; width: 420px;">contenido ultimo</div>
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="display: none; width: 420px;">contenido2</div>
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="display: none; width: 420px;">contenido 1</div>
</div>
```

He tratado de que no acumule para solo obtener en el div solo el ultimo , pensé usar .`html` pero el tema es que probé pero nose que linea tocar
alguna idea ?

El objetivo es obtener este resultado

```
<div class="ajax-file-upload-container">
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar" style="display: none; width: 420px;">contenido ultimo</div>
</div>
```

Este es el `js` `jquery.uploadfile.min.js`

Aquí lo descargue 
http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#single

Comment: Has probado a vaciar el HTML antes de meter un div nuevo? Es decir, borrar todos los hijos que tenga el div padre y luego meter el nuevo.

Comment: Debes modificar [esta función](https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/blob/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.js#L655). Primero debes verificar si ya existe un `div.ajax-file-upload-statusbar`, si no existe pues lo creas y lo agregas. O hacerlo en tu propio script como lo indica @GDP.

Comment: si trate de vaciar el div  puse al hacer    $("[type=file]").click(function(){
   $("ajax-file-upload-statusbar").html(" ");
});    pero i gual no limpia

Comment: Esa librería usa internamente eventos, el statusbar se crea en la función que ya dejé en mi comentario anterior, debes limpiar el container cuando el statusbar ya ha sido creado.

Comment: Por favor amigos , como verifico y limpio  podrian enseñarme?

Comment: he intentado esto pero sigue igual function defaultProgressBar(obj,s)
  {
            this.statusbar = '';
   this.statusbar = $("<div class='ajax-file-upload-statusbar'></div>").width(s.statusBarWidth);

Answer (score 0):

si salio gracias amigos

function defaultProgressBar(obj,s)
        {
            //alert(s);
            this.statusbar = $("").width(s.statusBarWidth);

```
        this.preview = $("<img class='ajax-file-upload-preview' />").width(s.previewWidth).height(s.previewHeight).appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();
        this.filename = $("<div class='ajax-file-upload-filename'></div>").appendTo(this.statusbar);
        this.progressDiv = $("<div class='ajax-file-upload-progress'>").appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();
        this.progressbar = $("<div class='ajax-file-upload-bar'></div>").appendTo(this.progressDiv);
        this.abort = $("<div>" + s.abortStr + "</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();
        this.cancel = $("<div>" + s.cancelStr + "</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();
        this.done = $("<div>" + s.doneStr + "</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();
        this.download = $("<div>" + s.downloadStr + "</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();
        this.del = $("<div>" + s.deletelStr + "</div>").appendTo(this.statusbar).hide();

        this.abort.addClass("ajax-file-upload-red");
        this.done.addClass("ajax-file-upload-green");
        this.download.addClass("ajax-file-upload-green");
        this.cancel.addClass("ajax-file-upload-red");
        this.del.addClass("ajax-file-upload-red");          
        // aqui mi aporte $(".ajax-file-upload-container").html(" ");

        return this;
    }
```